# Add comments in App.config in Winform application

Tags: c#, winforms, app-config, application-settings

I'm developing a windows application with C# . I need to add some comments into Application settings ( App.config ) 
Here is my App.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="SLTBillConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-BIJLHTG\Yuresh_SQL;Initial Catalog=SLTBillPaymentDB;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>

<appSettings>
    <add key="ScheduledTimeForNewDay" value="09" />
    <add key="KioskCode" value="0001" />
    <add key="IsMobitelPaymentEnable" value="false" />
    <add key="MaxChequeAmount" value="500000" />
    <add key="MinChequeAmount" value="10" />
</appSettings>
```

Comment: try html comment syntax `<!-- comment -->`

Answer (score 16):

Same as HTML, try `<!-- your comment -->`

Comment: It works ! Thank Ivien